# Excel formula to calculate the sum of positive and negative change of products

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, excel-formula, pivot

I have excel table in csv with data from monitoring smart shelf. The shelf status is monitored every 2 mins. The data is the table with time status of products at given time during the day. Each column consists of numbers e.g. 1,4,3,2,2,2,0,0 etc. When the number is bigger than previous one (e.g. was 2 and now is 3) it means that someone added the product to the shelf, and when the number is less than previous one, it means that the product unit/s was sold.

Te problem is to construct the formula that will be count quantity sold and quantity added. I think that it should monitor the change of quantity whether is positive or negative and sum each positive and negative change.
I just started learning excel more complex formulas and I don't have any idea how to solve this problem. I count on your help

Comment: You want two outputs, units added and units sold?  do we assume that an item cannot be added and removed in the same time period?

Comment: yes, I need two optuts: quantity added and quantity sold. There is no possibility to have the item added and removed in the same time period. The status of smart shelf is monitored all day and send to excel csv every 2 mins. I have this output from each day in excel table. In the first column is the time and the rest of columns are the the shelfs with quantity of products on given shelf at a time (every 2 mins status)

Comment: @Ewa but it is possible that within the 2 minute frame something is sold and added, surely? It’s an edge case but possible I would’ve thought. Regardless, an assumption needs to be made that an increase is a restock and a decrease is a sale.

Comment: This is not 2 minute frame, but all day. The status is monitor all the day and refresh every 2 mins, so the table looks like this, e.g. 12:04 1, 12:06 1, 12:08 2, where 1 and 2 is the quantity and 12:04 is time. On the basis of this data we can assume that at 12:08 1 unit was added to the shelf. The problem is how to monitor this changes and calculate quantity added and sold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sold

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A7-A2:A8,--(A1:A7>A2:A8))
```

Stocked

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A8-A1:A7,--(A2:A8>A1:A7))
```

[image]